# Load flexslider after a fancybox div has opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, flexslider

I've used flexslider and fancybox numerous times and both are great plugins. Separately, both these work great on a site I'm doing but the problem I'm going to describe now occurs when a flexslider gallery is places inside a fancybox div. I must point out this is a responsive website so there are no static widths, all widths are percentage based.

At first everything seems to be working. I load fancybox and flexslider displays as it should, its width 50% of the fancybox container. But if I add `display: none;` to the fancybox div which it needs to hide the div until its called upon, when fancybox loads all the images in flexslider are tiny, though the width of the flexslider div is correct. I'm assuming that because flexslider loads when the page does it has no idea what its width is. Which is why this doesn't occur when `display: none;` is set.

My javascript to load the 2 plugins currently looks like this:

```
// =FANCYBOX

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    padding : 2,
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    prevEffect: 'fade',
    title: false,
});

// =FLEXSLIDER 

$(function(){

    if($(".flexslider").length > 0) {
        $(".flexslider").addClass("loading");
        // Can also be used with $(document).ready()
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                directionNav: false,
                slideshowSpeed: 5000,
                animationSpeed: 360,
                easing: "easeInQuad",
                useCSS: false,
                start: function(slider){
                    $('.flexslider').removeClass('loading');
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Does anyone know how I can force flexslider to initialise again after fancybox is visible?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

Try initializing flexslider inside fancybox's `afterShow` callback like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding : 2,
        nextEffect: 'fade',
        prevEffect: 'fade',
        title: false,
        afterShow: function(){
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                // flexlslider options
            });
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

Comment: I thought that'd do it but the flexslider thumbnails are still too small. Small enough to show all 3 images in a line rather than just 1 the correct size :/ Thanks for the response!

Comment: Apologies, I've just realised this did work when I made some adjustments. Though I had to remove the standard flexslider call completely for this to work. Also, if a fancybox is loaded which doesn't contain a flexslider div. When one is opened that does have one it does what it did before. I guess in the standard flexslider load I need to exclude the flexslider in a fancybox div. And also, in the "afterShow" bit, only load a certain class of flexslider?

Comment: you could put a conditional to check if the slider exist like `if $(".fancybox-inner").find(".flexslider").length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid `display:none;` for fancybox, so flexslider can determine image size properly.

this trick may help you:

1. put fancybox div inside a parent div.
2. set `visibility:hidden;` for fancybox div.
3. set `display:none;` for parent div.

hope that it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately it didn't seem to work. I think the display none on the parent element must still collapse the div so it can't workout the height/width before it loads.